# Можно ли конвертировать объект sx в обычный для style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Я хочу получить из объекта:

```js
const sx = 
{
    display: "flex"
}
```

объект подобный:

```js
const sx =
{
    display: "-webkit-box",
    display: "-webkit-flex",
    display: "-ms-flexbox",
    display: "flex"
}
```

(MUI сам расставляет префиксы)

Comment: цель добавить нужные префиксы?

Comment: Да, именно. ...

Comment: `MUI сам расставляет префиксы` - есть доказательства, или какую роль играет это упоминание в вопросе? Могу ошибаться, но в ближайшем рассмотрении эта либа [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) может помочь

Comment: Я предполагаю, что именно MUI это делает. Если указать `style={{display: "flex"}}`, и посмотреть в стили devTools, мы не увидим точно такого же результата как от `sx={{display: "flex"}}`.

Comment: далеко не факт, насколько я знаю эту совместимость реализует сам реакт, правда я никогда это не проверял лично. Как я понимаю это нужно реализовать для `css in js` ?

Comment: `css in js` - можете конкретизировать? Я пишу стили в JS файле.

Comment: В `js` это и есть `css in js` если конечно не `инлайн стили в jsx` как с ними поступает реакт я не могу предсказать, хотя если бы решал я, я бы реализовывал совместимость и на инлайн уровне, как поступили разработчики реакта — сложно сказать, вообще нужно посмотреть `eject` реакта, чтобы найти настройки вебпака и модули которые этим занимаются, что касается `css in js` это обычно либы типа [этой](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.9.2)

Comment: Я этот объект в дальнейшем использую напрямую в `style` / `sx`, получается мне нужно то, что вы скинули по ссылочке?

Comment: возможно лучше использовать вариант по ссылке, если нет противопоказаний, а это уже известно только Вам, но вероятно их нет, опишите причину своего решения детальнее если не сможете определить сами

Comment: вот [пример](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-vendor-prefixer/?v=v10.9.2) из той же библиотеки чтобы определиться, он же [на гитхабе](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/tree/master/examples/plugins/jss-plugin-vendor-prefixer) так как в документации ссылка битая